# How to disable a LinkButton if Input elements do not have a value?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Like the title says, I'm trying to disable a LinkButton if certain Input elements do not have a value and enable if one of the Input elements do. I am just trying to disable the LinkButton if one of the Input elements does not hold a value for now, and this is what I have so far:

**Style**:

```
<style>
        .disabled-link
        {
            color: Gray;
        }
   </style>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
$(function() {
            $('select[id$=hdnSelectedOrganisations]').change(function() {
                var value = hdnSelectedOrganisations.value;
                var btnGenerateReport = $('a[id$=btnGenerateReport]')
                var href = btnGenerateReport.attr('href');
                if (value == null) {
                    btnGenerateReport.attr('href', '#').attr('myCustomAttr', href).addClass('disabled-link');
                }
                else {
                    linkButton1.attr('href', linkButton1.attr('myCustomAttr')).removeClass('disabled-link');
                }
            });
        $(document).ready(function ()
</script>
```

**Input Element to be read**:

```
                <div id="dOrganisationSearch" class="autosuggest-wrap clearfix">
                    <input type="text" id="txtClientName" runat="server" class="autosuggest client data_clientname" autocomplete="off" data-required="true" placeholder="Organisation" />
                            <input id="hdnClientID" runat="server" type="hidden" class="data_clientid" />
                            <div id="client-results" class="as-results as-results--modal"></div>

                    <p id="pSelectedOrganisations" runat="server" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;"></p>

                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedOrganisations" runat="server"/>
                </div>
```

**Button to be disabled**:

```
<div class="autosuggest-wrap clearfix" style="text-align:center;">
                    <button class="clear-filters lightblue view_btn att fillWidth" style="background-color: indianred; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 11px;">CLEAR ALL FILTERS</button>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" CssClass="lightblue view_btn att fillWidth" Text="Generate Report" />
                </div>
```

For some reason, no matter what I try, the button just won't disable. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The if condition is wrong, because HiddenField.value and TextBox.text will never be null. It is string empty by default.

you need to change the if below:

```
if (value == null) {
```

to:

```
if (value.trim() == "") {
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, you're right. I made that change and the button still isn't disabled though.

Comment: In that code you are only adding the style "disabled-link", that change the control's color. So, if you want to disable the control, you need to add attribute "disabled" or "disabled=true".